# How to subtract sales for month 1 and month 2 for every customer in my dataframe using pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy

**This is my data frame**
`

```
c = pd.DataFrame({"Product":["p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p3","p4","p4"],
                  "sales":[10000,20000,30000,40000,10000,24000,13000,20000],
                  "Month":["M1","M2","M1","M2","M1","M2","M1","M2"]})
```

[image]`

The answer should be another dataframe

I tired using boolean masking but I am not sure how to work with both the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = pd.DataFrame({"Product":["p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p3","p4","p4"],
                  "sales":[10000,20000,30000,40000,10000,24000,13000,20000],
                  "Month":["M1","M2","M1","M2","M1","M2","M1","M2"]})
c['sales'] = np.where(c['Month'] == "M2", c['sales'] * -1, c['sales'])
c.groupby('Product').sum()
```

This will work only in the case where you have only 'M1' and 'M2'

Comment: Yes thanks, this works, but is there a way to generalize this for a higher number of month ?

Comment: What do you mean? Let's say you have for the same product three months: 10, 11, 12. Do you want to subtract 10-11 and 11-12?

Comment: Okay so could we do something like, (10+11)-12 in a single go? my goal is to understand how to solve this for a more general set of data.